# how to remove duplicates in a row using sqlite having numbers which contains special characters

Tags: sqlite

I have a question which is similar to [Find the number of duplicates in a row using sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127837/find-the-number-of-duplicates-in-a-row-using-sqlite) except that the numbers mentioned in the column may contain brackets too . For eg:

```
Name       Num0     Num1     Num2   Num3   Num4  Num5   Num6  Num7  
1)John     (12)34   1234     (123)4 

2)Hebbar   234   

3)Jim      (9)876     9876    (9876)

4)Kim      111     111     111

5)Kate     666
```

Now when i run sqlite the query i should be getting the results as John, Jim and Kim respectively.
I am using C language for my project.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Remove the brackets with [replace()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace).

Comment: @CL.FYI.. Even if i use replace command, i should by no way update the same into my sqlite DB. I shiuld just get the results of my querry as John,Jim and Kim.

Comment: replace() is not a command but a function. I did not tell you to use UPDATE.

Comment: @CL.Can you please help me out with the query?Once i could get the names, then i have my own merging logic to take care of removing the duplicates. I need the query to get me the number of names which has duplicate numbers against its row.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the parentheses, use [replace()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) to replace them with an emptry string:

```
SELECT replace(replace(Num0, '(', ''), ')', '') AS Num0_without_parens,
       ...
FROM MyTable;
```

This can then be processed further, as shown in the linked question.